# Building subscription based application with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service, saas, multi-tenant, subscription

I am planning to write a subscription based application which will allow users to do the following:

- Subscribe/Sign-up to a plan (will select from multiple plans available)
- Will use subscription based billing solution e.g. Recurly, Chargify.
- Each client/user will see its own data
- Will have a REST API
- For now the plan is to have a shared database with multiple clients/users; but in future may need to scale to multi-tenant architecture.

I was wondering if there's already such an application available an open-source example. Any comments, reference to books is really appreciated.

Technologies I plan to use: Ruby on Rails, MySQL.

One of my primary requirement is to build a cost efficient solution. I am not sure how the Force platform can help me. Any comments on Sales Force platform would be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This book can help you

[http://www.amazon.com/Service-Oriented-Design-Rails-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0321659368](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321659368)

Answer (score 0):

The [SaaS Rails Kit](http://railskits.com/saas) (not free, and authored by me, so I'm obviously biased) would be a good starting point for you.